# How to use Direct Access Flow with Keycloak and ASP .NET for Authentication

Tags: asp.net, keycloak, openid-connect

I am trying to implement Authentication using Open ID Connect and Keycloak in my ASP .Net server. I want the user to authenticate using Keycloak, then I want to retrieve the access token and use it to authenticate (using Bearer Token) the user when I call an endpoint on my server.

I read that to use the KyeCloak's Direct Access flow (instead of the browser flow) I must tick the Standard flow to OFF.

Using .Net 7

**ASP .Net code in Program.cs:**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/GT/";
                options.ClientId = "gt_client";
                options.ClientSecret = "**********";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true; // MAYBE FOR ROLES
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;  // allow HTTP, only in development
                options.SaveTokens = true;

            });
```

**Keycloak client settings:**
[image]

**Endpoint I am calling:**

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("test")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

I authenticate user using (retrieving an access_token):
[image]

I get the following error when calling the endpoint:
*Client is not allowed to initiate browser login with given response_type*

I assume that I have to configure the code in my program.cs to tell keycloak to use the Direct Access that it skips the browser login and can directly access the endpoint using the access_token received from authenticating the user.

Note: If I set the [image] to on I get the login page when calling the endpoint:

[image]

Comment: You need to enable the Implicit Flow option in Keycloak client settings. After enabling it, it should work fine. You might want to add "options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";" into options of OpenID after adding scopes.

Comment: @ChinmayT That doesn't work. I have ticked the Implicit flow and added options.callback as you suggested, but when I call the endpoint I still get Brower Login (html) result back.